# $O_P(\cdot)$ and linearization (Taylor) under an expectation

Tags: probability, asymptotics

I have two independent random variable, $X,Y$, respectively standard $n$-dimensional Gaussian and uniform on $\{-1,1\}^n$. I let $X' := X/\sqrt{n}$, so that $X' = O_p(1)$.

*(here $O_P(\cdot)$ refers to [stochastic boundedness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_in_probability_notation) ("big Oh in probability"))*

I am confronted to an expression of the form
$$
\mathbb{E}[ \Phi(X)\mathbb{E}[ \Psi(\alpha\cdot\langle X',Y\rangle)\mid X]
$$
where $\alpha = o(1)$, and therefore $\alpha\cdot\langle X',Y\rangle = o_P(1)$ *(all the stochastic $O_P,o_p$ are wrt $X$)*. What I would like to do is to do a Taylor expansion of $ \Psi$ to second order  inside the inner expectation.

**My question:** is that "legit"? Are there more assumptions I need to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\Psi$ is second-order differentiable, then it makes no difference.  However, if $\Psi$ is a random function, then you may have more issues.  For example, if $\Psi(X) = 1$ for almost all realizations of $X$, then there is no harm in doing a Taylor expansion.

However, knowing that $\alpha \cdot \langle X', Y \rangle = o_P(1)$ may not be enough to calculate the expectation.  I would assume you want to show something like the fact that the expectation tends to zero, but knowing probability bounds is not quite enough. Essentially, while your expression is $o_P(1)$, you do not know about the part that is not covered by the probability.   You may need to appeal to Slutsky's theorem (or something similar).

To elaborate, suppose $|Z| = o_P(1)$.  Then even a simple calculation shows \begin{align} E|Z| &= \int_{|Z| < \varepsilon}|Z| dP + \int_{|Z| \geq \varepsilon} |Z|dP\\
&\leq \varepsilon P(|Z| < \varepsilon) + \int_{|Z| \geq \varepsilon}|Z|dP.
\end{align}
Even though the first term above is tending to one, knowing $|Z| = o_P(1)$ is not enough to show that the expectation also tends to zero (although it still may under some regularity conditions).

Comment: What do you mean with your first sentence, exactly? I don't get it.

Comment: If $\Psi: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is twice continuously differentiable, then no matter what values of $X$ are realized, $\Psi$ will still be differentiable.  You can always do a Taylor expansion, you just need to check that $X$ falls into the open interval in which you are doing such an expansion with high probability.

Comment: But my question (in case it wasn't clear, sorry) is about under what assumptions I can integrate this $o_p$ or $O_p$. I was not worried about the expansion itself, but about what happens to it when taking its expectation.

Comment: See my example above.  In general, you can't (convergence in probability does not imply convergence in expectation).  If you are trying to show convergence in distribution, then it is enough to show convergence in probability and appeal to Slutsky's theorem (for example).

Comment: Thank you. ${}{}{}$